# Qt .executable runs but the UI won't show up

Tags: qt, qml, exe, executable, msvc12

I have a project that I'm trying to generate an executable for.
At first I just went into the "build-myproject\release" folder and tried to run the .exe file but it asked for some .dll files, so I went to the proper compiler directory (C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013\bin in my case) to grab those dll files.
[image: build release directory with dll files]
Now when I try to run the executable the program runs (I can see it in the task manager)
[image: exe in task manager]
but there's no Qml gui that shows up (I also set visible: true in main.qml)... My program runs great in QtCreator
[image]
but nothing happens when I run the executable.
Can any one please help me? Thank you.

Comment: You could run it through the cmd.

Comment: so I navigated to the executable through the command line and ran "DIC.exe" and nothing happened... I dont even see it in the task manager.

Comment: You could print logs indicating if the window is visible to verify up to what point it is running.

Comment: I placed a qDebug statement in the main then I ran it in the cmd and also by double clicking it but nothing happened.

Comment: Read the instructions about deployment of Qt applications Windows. It's not just copying "some .dll files" (and, besides, *which ones did you copy*? Did you copy the plugins? Did you copy the required QML modules?).

Comment: You want to use `windeployqt`. Find more here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html - ask again if you still have problems.

Comment: If you are using Qt 5.9.2 or 5.10 beta it might be related to this bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63770 that has now been solved.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using Qt 5.8. I ran the windeployqt.exe with --qmldir, placed the dll files that the .exe was asking for and also copied over the modules and plugins folder to the "release" directory.